# Downgrading from Boost 1.37 to 1.34

Tags: c++, boost

I have to update an application to use Boost 1.34 instead of 1.37, and it's causing me a ton of trouble.

One of the biggest problems at the moment is that I don't know Boost threads very well. With 1.34, I get...

`error C2039: 'this_thread' : is not a member of 'boost'`

...for the code

`boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));`

boost::posix_time is not in 1.34 either.

Does anyone know the equivilant Boost 1.34 function calls?

Comment: it is possible (i don't know) that those functions simply didn't exist yet in 1.34...

Comment: boost::posix_time seems to exist (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time)

Comment: The required header files changed. I found it, thanks.

Comment: Sorry to ask but -- why would you need to downgrade Boost?

Comment: Because 1.37 does not compile with Visual Studio 2003 and its components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`boost::thread::sleep`](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=9&ct=rc#Kj_UX-Q5_iA/trunk/third_party/boost_1_34_1/boost/thread/thread.hpp) takes a [`struct xtime`](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=9&ct=rc#Kj_UX-Q5_iA/trunk/third_party/boost_1_34_1/boost/thread/xtime.hpp) in 1.34.1. Try this:

```
struct xtime timeout;
timeout.sec = 0;
timeout.nsec = 500 * 1000000;
boost::thread::sleep(timeout);
```

Answer (score 1):

boost::thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::ptime(...));

Comment: Changing `this_thread` to `thread` helped, thanks. However, `posix_time` is not defined. Any ideas for that?